# Can undefinied nodes be converted via scripts?

Tags: scripting, node-editor

I have a blend file that was made in a earlier version of blender and now a lot of nodes are labeled as "undefined". I don't remember what these nodes were, but I do know how to replace them. All of these Undefined nodes need to be converted into 'Mapping' nodes. Is there a way to automate this process of changing these undefined nodes into these mapping nodes?

In the pic below I simply manually added the Mapping node and changed the flow. Example file: http://www.mediafire.com/file/ypbtuinri3ntzmq/file
[image]

Comment: Can you build a small example .blend that has one of these materials mapped to a cube or something? I know how I'd do it in theory, but it would be nice to test before I post an answer...

Comment: I added the example file to the OP, but here it is again: http://www.mediafire.com/file/ypbtuinri3ntzmq/file

Comment: What you posted doesn't have an 'Undefined' node? In the mean time, I found a [post on Blender Artists](https://blenderartists.org/t/import-and-replace-nodes/1165713/9) that kind of does what you're asking for.

Answer (score 0):

Very strange. I was the one who asked this question, but my account doesn't say I asked it and I cannot comment on the Ron Jensen comment chain. The solution to my problem was that I was using blender 2.8 and updating to 2.83 LTS changed the node from Undefined and back to Mapping.